# Define variables in cypress.env.json

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to define global variables for my tests of the selected application. I want to input them into one file - after reading the documentation I decided to use `cypress.env.json`.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-1-cypress-json

As I see variables are imported correctly, but during the test, I get the error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined"
```

Any suggestions on how to fix that problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K26vU.png

Test file:

```
describe('/register', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('/#/register')
    })

    it.only('requires username', () => {
        cy.get('input[type="email"]').Cypress.env('correctEmail')
        cy.get('input[type="password"]').Cypress.env('correctPassword')
        cy.get('button').contains('Sign in').click()
        cy.get('.error-messages').should('contain', 'username can\'t be blankis too short (minimum is 1 character)')
    })
```

cypress.env.json:

```
{
    "correctName": "Bob Ross",
    "incorrectName": "Bobbbbb",
    "correctEmail": "bob@ross.eu",
    "incorrectEmail": "b@bbb",
    "correctPassword": "bobrosss",
    "incorrectPassword": "Oooooo" 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `env` variables into `cypress.json` in the root folder like this:

```
     {
       "env": {
         "correctName": "Bob Ross",
         "incorrectName": "Bobbbbb",
         "correctEmail": "bob@ross.eu",
         "incorrectEmail": "b@bbb",
         "correctPassword": "bobrosss",
         "incorrectPassword": "Oooooo" 
       },
     }
```

Also I see one more issue in your code. If you want to type into input field, you have to use `.type` command like this:

```js
cy.get('input[type="email"]').type(Cypress.env('correctEmail'));
```

Comment: Already tried - the same result. I moved  cypress.env.json into another folder, as I checked in settings - Cypress found correctly variables from cypress.json, but the issue is still the same.

Comment: Thank you - so there was problem with code, not importing. : )

Comment: @Piecho3a, what were you not importing? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 14):

To answer your original question, the `cypress.env.json` file needs to be placed inside the root of your project, right next to the `cypress.json` file.

By creating a separate cypress.env.json file you're able to access nested values, like so:

```
//cypress.env.js
{
    "user": {
        "username": "Jane",
        "password": "SuperPassword",
        "someOtherData": "veryImportantData"
    }
}
```

and then

```
//somewhere in myCypressTest.spec.ts
Cypress.env("user").username      //returns "Jane"
Cypress.env("user").password      //returns "SuperPassword"
Cypress.env("user").someOtherData //returns "veryImportantData"
```

It's not really documented accurately anywhere unfortunately. I didn't need to change any paths, just moved the `cypress.env.json` outside the Cypress folder where I had originally placed it, and it started working.

Comment: This does not work for me.  I get - Cannot read property 'signals' of undefined

Comment: @SteveTomlin can you show me your cypress.env.json file?

Comment: Its ok I discovered the reason it was breaking was because I had imported Cypress in the top. I removed the import and now it works

Comment: @SteveTomlin Super :)