# How to Re-use auth token across multiple pages in cypress

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I have a Rest API that generates token which is used in multiple REST API's as an authorization Bearer token.
I used it as seen in my code below and it worked fine.

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
const user = { 
    url_01:   ("/"),
    token:     "Hardcoded token from postman here"
};

describe('some text here', () => {

    it('some text here', () => {
      cy.request({
          method: 'POST',
          url: user.url_01,

          headers: {
                "authorization": user.token
          },
          body: {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "createdBy" : "John",
            "services":"services",
          }
      }).then((res)=>{
            expect(res.status).to.eq(201)
      })
  
      })
```

But my challenge is that I want to use same token on different pages and I don't want to be hardcoding it as I did on first page.

I want it hardcoded in one place, say support/command.js or somewhere else; then I can call it from there and use it anywhere I want.

But I can't seem to work my way through that on support/command.js.

I've googled and even attempted the answer given on "Cypress:Re-use auth token across multiple API tests" on this platform, still, it isn't working for me.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add a env variable to your cypress.json file. There are also ways to create a cypress.env.json where you can add all your secrets.Here is a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832494/define-variables-in-cypress-env-json-

Comment: @ItsNotAndy Thanks man!!!
The first option on the reference worked well for me. Will try the second option for something else later.
I truly appreciate!